# Qualification or Disqualification of Machine Intelligence test as "Turing test"?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

Let's us the following definition:

**Tu·ring test** *noun*

> A test for intelligence in a computer, requiring that **a human being** should be unable to distinguish the machine from **another human** being by using the replies to questions put to both.

Also observe from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_test):

> The Turing test is a test, developed by Alan Turing in 1950, of a machine's ability to exhibit intelligent behaviour equivalent to, or indistinguishable from, **that of a human**.

Notice in each case *a human* (singular) is pitted against the demonstrated intelligence of *another human* (singular);  **WHETHER** against an actual human or a machine exhibiting behaviour *equivalent* to or *indistinguishable* from the intellect of *a human's int* (again, singular).

In this [article](https://davidcarmel.org/2014/02/21/did-ibm-watson-pass-the-turing-test/) the question was asked whether IBM's Watson pass the Turing test. Yet Watson did not demonstrate intelligence of a single human but that of an entire team of programmers and the community of chess expertise they relied upon.

By definition Turing did not propose a test of *a human* against *a community of humans* (plural) **OR** against a machine exhibiting intelligent behaviour *equivalent* to or *indistinguishable* from *a community of humans* (plural) since **whether a machine is artificially intelligent or not, a single human can nearly always be flummoxed by a community of humans given a sufficiently large community (one or more intellects).**  Definitions in Science are precise.

Turing's test contained the self-ordained constraint that apparent 'machine intelligence' approximated by the Turing test exhibit the approximate intelligence of a single human rather than an entire community of humans.  Because of these differences the Turing Test must be distinguishable from other non-Turning Tests.

**QUESTION**:

> If **Computer Science** by definition, deals with the theory and methods of processing information in digital computers including artificial intelligence, and as a matter of pragmatics, on what basis are tests between human and machine qualified or disqualified as Turing test as Turing proposed them, or some other type of test Turing didn't conceive of (say non-Turing test for artificial intelligence)?

Comment: The imitation game (what some people call a Turing test) was just a sample thought experiment that Turing used to explore the philosophical question of whether machines can think. He did not formally define a win in the game as a necessary and sufficient indicator of intelligence. Formally defining intelligence and designing a proper "Turing test" is still an open question that philosophers are wrestling with. I think you are taking the wrong approach here by overanalyzing vague and paraphrased definitions.

Comment: (cont.) You might be best served by reading Turing's original paper on the matter. http://loebner.net/Prizef/TuringArticle.html

Comment: Thank you.   If  you believe that paper answers the question, might I ask why you didn't provide a response citing the paper?  Whats the harm, if not risk having people agree or disagree with your answer?  Can you explain why Turing's original paper addresses the question, except provide an answer rather than a comment.  With respect to the test being a 'thought experiment', Einstein's General Theory of Relativity started a thought experiment.  Is it not prudent to ask what Turning meant?

Comment: 1. Please ask only one question per question.  This site's format doesn't work so well when you try to ask more than one question in a single post.  Instead, please ask each question separately, in its own post.  It might be helpful to edit this post to focus on just one of the questions, and post the other one separately.  2. I don't know how well you know our format, but our site is aimed at questions that admit an objectively correct answer. If your goal is to have a discussion about the topic, then you shouldn't be asking here.  See our [help/dont-ask].

Comment: No the goal was to obtain an answer.  Ill remove one of the questions ..

Comment: I didn't suggest Turing's paper because I thought it would answer your question. I suggested it because I thought it might help you clarify some confusion you might have about what Turing proposed. I don't think it is wise for me to attempt to answer your question since I can't really accept premises behind the definitional approach you are taking. To me it seems like you're going off track and creating issues from non-issues. On top of that, your current question asks about qualifications for what a valid Turing test is according to Turing, which he never made as far as I know.

Comment: Ah, thanks again.  I didn't realize I was confused about what Turing wrote.  Rather I was confused about how computer scientists distinguish valid from invalid 'Turing tests' as the question indicated.  The focus is on application rather than theory.